# Cut a 35degree badge into a image with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

How should I create this white badge on the top left corner with CSS only ? I created on approach but its honestly really bad I think. I created a white area (rectangle) which i transformed by 35degrees and tried to position it as good as possible at this corner. Aligning the text for the badge I did the same way, but its not really pretty and I have some problems as well as you can see in the image above. I am curious how you guys would do it ?

My try:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item-img"><a href="images/packages/background01.jpg" rel="imagebox" title="SockMonkee"><img src="images/packages/background01.jpg" alt=""/><div class="overlay zoom"></div></a></div>
<div class="checkout-badge">
    <div class="checkout-price"><span>€</span>30</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.checkout-badge {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-35deg) translateY(0);
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: -50px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.checkout-price {
    color: #2da0ce;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.checkout-price span {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: -60px;
}
```

Comment: All you need is `overflow: hidden` and a common wrapper for the label and the image to apply it on.

Comment: Hm I tried to add overflow:hidden to my .checkout-badge in my css, but I couldn't see any change. I didn't get at all what you meant by the rest

Comment: He means something like: http://jsfiddle.net/z1cf8r4c/ . Too hacky for an answer, but that should get you or someone else started.

Comment: The overflow:hidden solved it, ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't render the whole rectangle. I'd build a triangle with CSS and overlay it in the corner. This would mean you wouldn't have other elements covered by your badge. Here's a decent article about the various shapes you can make with CSS alone: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nQsU9KESJ7ZLVkwHlDPQ?p=preview

Here's the HTML. I also included the badge within the `div` containing the image.

```
<div class="item-img">
    <a href="images/packages/background01.jpg">
        <img src="images/packages/background01.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="checkout-badge">
        <div class="checkout-price"><span>€</span>30</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.item-img {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #009;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.checkout-badge {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 75px solid #fff;
  border-right: 105px solid transparent;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.checkout-price {
  color: #2da0ce;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: -55px;
  left: 15px;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
}
```

I'd play around with the numbers and style. You can adjust the border widths to make different types of triangles. Using the same width will produce an isosceles right triangle, but your transform would need to be `-45deg` to fit the angle. Also, changing which border sides (and position) will allow you to place the border in whichever corner of the image you want e.g. top + left = upper-left, top + right = upper-right, etc.

Comment: So the border-top in combination with border-right is doing the magic to crop a triangle into the corner ? Never seen this, thank you - Going to try this now

Comment: Hm this doesn't work for me as far as I tested. Is it a problem that my actual image is inside the div "item-img" included with the normal <img src=""> ?

Comment: I updated the answer to include a working anchor and image. I didn't try extracting the `img` from the `div`. I just used relative/absolute positioning for the parent `div` and badge.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a simple implementation of what you're looking for:

```css
.wrap{
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  }
.price{
  position:absolute;
  padding-top:30px;
  top:-10%;
  left:-20%;
  transform:rotate(-35deg);
  background:white;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;
  color: #2da0ce;
  }

.image1{
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/200);
  }
.image2{
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  }


/*hover effect*/

a, .price{
  transition: all 0.8s;
  }
a:hover{
  opacity:0.5;
  }

.price:hover{
  opacity:100%;
  background: black;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="wrap image1">
  <div class="price">£20</div>
</a>

<a href="#" class="wrap image2">
  <div class="price">£20</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Browser compatibility for transform: rotate**

```
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+
     -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15
      -ms-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* IE 9
       -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00
          transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+
}
```

**Browser compatibility for transition**

```
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

**transparent does not work in IE8**
According to *StatCounter* as of Dec. 2014, 15% of US Browsers used are IE8

**To work on 100% of Browsers it would require the image be altered.**

I'd edit the image file in PHP with the GD extension. Then I would not have to be concerned about Browser compatibility.

This is if the images were up loaded in a pre-production process:

**OPTIONAL: Get the image and type and scale to size.**
This is a bullet proof way to insure the type of image

```
if( is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']) || !($_FILES['image1']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)){
  $save = false;
  $jspan = '';
  $gspan = '';
  $pspan = '';
  switch(strtolower($_FILES['image1']['type'])){
  case 'image/jpeg':
    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/png':
    $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  case 'image/gif':
    $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
  default:
    $img = @getimagesize($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
    switch(strtolower($img['mime'])){
    case 'image/jpeg':
      $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/png':
      $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    case 'image/gif':
      $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
      if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
    default:
      $filename = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
      $ext = substr($filename,-3);
      switch(strtolower($ext)){
      case 'jpg':
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'gif':
        $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      case 'png':
        $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      default:
        $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
        $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        if ($image !== false){$save = true;break;}
      }
    }
  }
}
 if ($save === true){
  $originalWidth  = imagesx($image);
  $originalHeight = imagesy($image);
  $scale      = min($previewWidth/$originalWidth, $previewHeight/$originalHeight);
  $newWidth  = ceil($scale*$originalWidth);
  $newHeight = ceil($scale*$originalHeight);
  $newPic = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
  imagecopyresampled($newPic, $image,0, 0, 0, 0,$newWidth, $newHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
```

**OPTIONAL: Find the optimum image type**

```
  ob_start();
  imagejpeg($newPic, NULL, 70);
  $jpg = ob_get_clean();
  ob_clean();
  ob_end_flush();
  $jLen = strlen($jpg);
  ob_start();
  imagepng($newPic, NULL, 9);
  $png = ob_get_clean();
  ob_clean();
  ob_end_flush();
  $pLen = strlen($png);
  ob_start();
  imagegif($newPic);
  $gif = ob_get_clean();
  ob_clean();
  ob_end_flush();
  $gLen = strlen($gif);
  if ($gLen < $jLen){
    if ($pLen < $gLen){
      $raw = $png;
      $png = null;
      $type = 'png';
      $pspan = '<span class="size">';
    }
    else{
      $raw = $gif;
      $gif = null;
      $type = 'gif';
      $gspan = '<span class="size">';
    }
  }
  elseif($pLen < $jLen){
    $raw = $png;
    $png = null;
    $type = 'png';
    $pspan = '<span class="size">';
  }
  else{
    $raw = $jpg;
    $jpg = null;
    $type = 'jpg';
    $jspan = '<span class="size">';
  }
```

**THE ABOVE IS OPTIONAL**
The above could be replaced with:

```
$image = @imagecreatefromjpeg(/home/user/public_html/images/image.jpg');
```

**The rest of this code would on take a few milliseconds to execute.**
It would work well on the fly while creating the HTML.

**Create the white tag with text and rotate**

```
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
$im = imagecreate(100, 100);
$string = '€ 30';
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
imagechar($im, 0, 50, 20, $string, $blue);
$corner = imagerotate($im, 45, 0);
```

**Merge the white corner on to the scaled new image.**

```
imagecopymerge($newPic , $corner , 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 75);
```

I prefer using base64 images and put them in the HTML to save all the HTTP Requests fro each image.

```
$base64 = base64_encode($raw);
$image = "<img  width=\"$newWidth\" height=\"$newHeight\" src=\"data:image/$type;base64,$base64\" "/>";


  $image = mysql_escape_string($image );
  @mysql_unbuffered_query("UPDATE `photos` SET `image `='$image ' WHERE `id`=$id");
```

**To save the image**

```
  $filename = "image$id." . $type;
  $fp = fopen($filename  ,"w");
  fwrite($fp, $raw);
  fclose($fp);
  imagedestroy($newPic);
```

This process only take a few milliseconds.  The upload take all the time.

So if doing it on the fly rather then doing the upload images:
Replace the top two seconds of code with this:

```
$filename = "/home/user/pic/$imagename";
$imgage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

Comment: This isn't really a useful answer. Showing them HOW is a useful answer.

Comment: I know that PHP isn't a tag for this question, but seriously. SOMETIMES people should just use JavaScript or a server side language to achieve a result with little to no issues with browser compatibility.

Comment: And I agree with Seth. An example would be great!

Comment: I would have but I do not know where the images are coming from and how often they change.  It probably should be a pre-production process.  It could be done on the fly to.  It would only take milliseconds per image.